# How to call a method in the instance which created an instance of me

Tags: python, instance

Following problem with a little example for the better understanding:

Let´s say I create an instance "driver1" of the class Driver. In the constructor of this class, an instance "passenger" of the class Passenger is created. In the class Passenger is a method need_to_pee(). How do I realize, that the method  "passenger_has_to_pee" of the instance who created this instance of class Passenger is called ( in this case driver1 )?

Sry for this kind of stupid question, but I'm new to the world of programming...

Thanks a lot!

```
class Passenger:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

        #callbackMethod
    def need_to_pee(self):
        #run the method  "passenger_has_to_pee" of the instance who created an Instance of me

class Driver:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.passenger = Passenger("Nick")

    def passenger_has_to_pee(self):

        self.drive_to_toilett()

    def drive_to_toilett(self):
        print("")


driver1 = Driver("John")
```

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `Passenger` should include a reference to the `Driver` (or more generally, whatever object is supplying the `passenger_has_to_pee` method, regardless of its type).

```
class Passenger:

    def __init__(self,name, driver):
        self.name = name
        self.driver = driver

    def need_to_pee(self):
        self.driver.passenger_has_to_pee()

class Driver:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.passenger = Passenger("Nick", self)

    def passenger_has_to_pee(self):

        self.drive_to_toilett()

    def drive_to_toilett(self):
        print("")
```

Comment: Thank you. So this should also work if i have multiple instances of Driver? Lets say

driver1 = Driver() driver2 = Driver()

and so on...?

Comment: Yes, since each instance of `Driver` will pass itself to any passenger it creates.

Comment: Essentially, there is a many-to-one relationship between `Passenger` instances and `Driver` instances, and `Driver.__init__` itself gets to enforce the one-driver-per-passenger constraint.